# Custom Control missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

A friend of mine created a control(Multi Select Combo Box) and compiled it into a DLL. I have added the DLL to my references and namespace in my WPF window as such:

```
xmlns:mc="clr-namespace:MultiSelectComboBox;assembly=MultiSelectComboBox"
```

When using the control:

```
<mc:MultiSelectUserControl Name="mscControl" />
```

The problem is once i add the xaml to use the control, the window goes gray with Invalid Markup.
The error list shows 2 errors, ie:

> The name "MultiSelectUserControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MultiSelectComboBox;assembly=MultiSelectComboBox".

And

> The type 'mc:MultiSelectUserControl' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

but if i run the application, the control works perfectly. Its just extremely frustrating designing the GUI when this keeps happening. I did do research on it but came up with nothing helpful.

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try cleaning your solution, rebuilding the project and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: I have done that quite a few times. Clean, rebuild, restart VS and Created an entire new project but still the same thing

Comment: is the solution in a network folder?

Comment: @Calvin Smith: Right now the solution is in My Documents on local drive.

Comment: My problem was it was a network drive. There are many known bugs with xaml in VS

Comment: @CalvinSmith: Thanks, will do some research to check if this is a bug

Comment: Is there any code (i.e. in the constructor of the `MultiSelectComboBox`) that cannot be executed within the VS designer? You have to know that the VS as well as the Blend designer are just a special runtime for your controls - if you do e.g. service calls these will result in exceptions that will prevent the designer from showing you the layout at design time.

Comment: Maybe just the name mismatch between UserControl and ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally Agreed with feO2X : 
The main reason behind error will always be the some code(in constructor of user control) which calls any particular service or any runtime function,

If any, user control will not be allowed to load it properly in xaml design.
so I would recommend please ask your friend does he made any call in the constructor of his own user control then he should not do this in current scenario. what he can do is make one extra function,place all the codes(except InitializeComponent) and call that particualr function in loaded event of particular user control and there will be no problem at all in functionality as well